# Invisible cursor when using dual monitor

Tags: 14.04, cursor, multiple-monitors

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.3 64bit with lastest updates installed and I have two Dell monitors.
I used DVI and VGA to connected them with my PC.
I connect one monitor with PC, then start ubuntu, then connect second monitor. Everything runs well, the cursor is still visible. Then I shutdown the PC and restart it and the cursor is gone but still working ( can right click ) but it is invisible.
When I remove a monitor, then restart PC, the cursor is visible again.

Can somebody please help me?
Thank you and sorry about my English.

Comment: Are you using the proprietary video driver?

Comment: What is your actual question? Because the answer to “Can someone please help me?” is either “yes” or “no”, depending on what you need help with and the knowledge of the answering person.

Comment: @Daniel I'm using graphic card onboard and i didnt install anything to my Ubuntu.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Sorry bro, my english is bad.

Comment: @Hieu: My critique isn't about your mastery of a particular language. As far as I can tell, you only describe a situation and don't even attempt to express explicitly, what you want. I can guess, that you probably want to render the mouse pointer visible, but that draws on many implicit assumptions.

Comment: Try This. WARNING: It will delete the loader splash screen.
http://askubuntu.com/a/739520/512046 But it's working for me.

Comment: I inadvertently fixed the disappearing cursor issue on 20.04 for my setup. Plugging in a monitor changed my fractional scaling. I went back and changed the Fractional Scaling from 200% back to 125% under Settings -> Displays -> Scale. After doing this, my disappearing cursor issue went away.

Answer (score 1):

My cursor is going away sometime on one of my monitors.
Using "Change of user" and logging back makes it visible again, without a need to reboot or close all my session. Cool.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try the proprietary nvidia/amd video drivers all you have to do is:

1. Open Dash  (press the windows key)
2. Search for `Additional Drivers`
3. Check the proprietary nvidia/adm driver, wait to install and the restart the PC.

If it didn't solve anything you can always repeat the steps and go back to the defaul opensource drivers

Comment: Not work bro. :'(

Comment: Doesn't work and i lost my primary monitor. I'm in trouble now. :S

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem on my workstation (an i7 intel NUC5i7RYH w/ a HDMI and display link connection running your same version of ubuntu).  I tried everything I could think of to fix the issue (updating/changing drivers, switching out monitors/mouse, updating OS, restarting lightdm).  Nothing seemed to work.  Then a coworker told me he **solved the problem by setting the HDMI monitor as his primary monitor in BIOS** following a BIOS update.  That odd configuration change solved the issue.  Updating the BIOS without the config change did not solve the issue.  I suspect Intel will fix this issue in the near future.

Of note, I was using your same solution involving a PC restart with only one monitor connected as my initial solution.

Comment: Just start our PC with both of your monitors, of course the curson will disappear, but you can press `Ctrl + Alt + L`, the curson will visible.

Comment: Hieu.  That works as well, but only recently.  Apparently, one of the ubuntu  updates allowed the "logout" solution you mention above.  I wanted a permanent fix and the bios change accomplished this.  Thanks for the feedback though.  It will likely benefit someone else who doesn't have the bios option.

Comment: My BIOS has nothing to set the primary monitor. Temporary, I'm using DVI cable to connect first monitor, and HDMI to DVI to second monitor.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I have tried all the driver changes posted here and elsewhere.  Non of any of that helped.  So, I went back to an old trick someone showed me once.  When all else fails:

1. Shut your pc down.
2. Unplug your pc.
3. remove the pc's battery.
4. Wait 30 minutes then reverse what you did.

Shazaam!  It worked!  This seems to be a fix to most of my pc issues.  I suppose it allows garbage that accumulates in ram to disappear.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Go to: *All Settings / Displays*

Then select third monitor (*Unknown Display*), set it to *OFF* and click *Apply*.

Check the cursor, if everything is fine then click *Keep This Configuration*.

That solves this problem for mee on *Ubuntu 14.04*, *15.10* and *16.04*.